# How can i add headers to ktor request if i use submitFormWithBinaryData()?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kmm

Code below is to upload an file using ktor and kmm ...

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache) {}
    val file = File("path/to/some.file")
    val chatId = "123"
    
    client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
        url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=$chatId",
        formData = formData {
            append("document", file.readBytes(), Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name}")
            })
        }
    )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i use ktor with kotlin multiplatform  exactly i write ktor code in shared module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that using the `submitFormWithBinaryData` method. Use the [post](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.request/post.html?query=inline%20suspend%20fun%20HttpClient.post(block:%20HttpRequestBuilder.()%20-%3E%20Unit):%20HttpResponse) or [request](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.request/request.html?query=fun%20request(block:%20HttpRequestBuilder.()%20-%3E%20Unit):%20HttpRequestBuilder) method. Here is an example:

```
client.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument?chat_id=$chatId") {
    header("custom", "value")
    body = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
        append("document", file.readBytes(), Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name}")
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but when i use your code it return this error    /*kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'MultiPartFormDataContent' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.*/

Comment: Do you send an explicit `Content-Type` header with a value `application/json`?

Comment: no i will comment with code i written now

Comment: You have the line `contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)` that sends the `Content-Type` header with `application/json` value. This causes the SerializationException because the `JsonFeature` tries to serialize `MultiPartFormDataContent` object. To make it work remove that line.

Answer (score -2):

this is my code ...

```
     val response = client.post<String>("${PublicData.BASEURL}"+"classes/UserFiles"){
                headers {
                    append("X-Parse-Application-Id", PublicData.Application_Id )
                    append("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", PublicData.REST_API_Key)
                    append("Content-Type", "application/json")
                }
    
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                body =  MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
                    headersOf("X-Parse-Application-Id", PublicData.Application_Id)
                    headersOf("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", PublicData.REST_API_Key)
                    append("file_type", "Ktor klogo")
                    append("encryption_tool_id", "Ktorkk logo")
                    append("user_id", "Ktor kklogo")
                    append("query", "Ktor kklogo")
                    append("file", file, Headers.build {
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=asd")
                    })
                })
    
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).